# Redirect sitemap.xml to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On an ASP.NET MVC 5 site I have the following action:

```
[Route("site/map"), HttpGet]
public virtual SitemapResult Map() {
}
```

I want to redirect sitemap.xml to this action so I added:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("sitemap", "sitemap.xml", new { controller = "Site", action = = "Map" });
```

But when I access sitemap.xml I get a 404 error. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code below to you the handler section of the web.config:

```
<add name="SiteMap" path="sitemap.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```